# Css property for columns

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I have some text that I want to display in 2 Columns. I did this using the css properties as you can see below:

```
.merchant-filialheader .merchant-rightside {
  -moz-column-count:2;
  -webkit-column-count:2;
  column-count:2;
  /* IE9 or lower just have 1 column */
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

The problem is that if I have not so much text, then the text still gets split into 2 columns. Therefore, I tried to set a `min-height`. Now it works for small text pieces, but when I get large amounts of text some parts get cut off.

Any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DYZhU/
Here is a jsfiddle. it's pretty simple, but when you uncomment the min-height. some of the text get cut.

Comment: I can't replicate it. It renders just fine no matter how much text I put there, or how I resize the window.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DYZhU/2/ . The problem is that i want to have a min size (because i dont want that the text is balanced, i want it to float from the first column, to the 2nd column) the problem is if i set the min-height value and i get a large amount of text not all text is displayed (in that case the box should be higher)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `column-fill: auto;`. It seems that browsers implement multiple columns with `column-fill:balanced` by default.

I only tested it on Firefox and IE10, and it seems only to work on Firefox with `-moz-column-fill:auto;`. According to the [W3C reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-fill.asp), no browsers support this yet.

You can see it in action (on Firefox) here: http://jsfiddle.net/Trickery/GqMXn/